# Invertibility of Hermitian Square

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $x$ be some element in a unital $C^*$-algebra. Is it true that if $x^*x$ is invertible, then $x$ is invertible?

Answer (score 3):

No. The standard counterexample is the shift $x\colon \ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}), x e_n =e_{n+1}$. It satsifies $x^\ast x=1$, but $x$ is clearly not surjective.

Invertibility of $x^\ast x$ only implies the existence of a left inverse for $x$. To get invertibility of $x$ it is necessary and sufficient that both $x^\ast x$ and $xx^\ast$ are invertible.

Comment: Also, there is a class of C*-algebras called "finite" C*-algebras in which left invertibility implies right invertibility. All finite dimensional C*-algebras are clearly finite, but so are some infinite dimensional ones - for instance, AF algebras.

Comment: Indeed. Another important class are the reduced group $C^\ast$-algebras of discrete groups.

Comment: @MaoWao Really? That's interesting. So left invertibility implies right invertibility in reduced group $C^*$-algebras What about the group $C^*$-algebra or the $C^*$-algebra generated by a unitary representation of a group?

Comment: @MaoWao And do you have some references?

Comment: @MaoWao I think I'll start a new question.