# Left Invertibility Implies Right Invertibility in Certain $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, inverse, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is a follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552674/invertibility-of-hermitian-square). In it, it was noted that in certain $C*$-algebras, left invertibility implies right invertibility. It was stated that AF-algebras have this property. Are there any other classes of $C*$-algebras that have this property? I don't know much about $C^*$-algebras at this point in my career, but I'm wondering if the group $C^*$-algebra or the $C^*$-algebra of generated by a unitary representation of a group have this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a good characterization of when C*-algebras have this property. A projection $p \in A$ is called finite if whenever $0 \leq q \leq p$ and $q$ is Murray-von Neumann equivalent to $p$ (i.e., there exists a partial isometry such that $v^*v = q$ and $vv^* = p$), then $q = p$. A unital C*-algebra is called finite if the unit is.

See Lemma 5.1.2. in Rørdam's "An Introduction to K-Theory for C*-Algebras."  The following are equivalent for a unital C*-algebra $A$.

1. $A$ is finite.
2. All isometries in $A$ are unitary.
3. All projections in $A$ are finite.
4. Every left-invertible element in $A$ is invertible.
5. Every right-invertible element in $A$ is invertible.

Note that an element having both a left and right inverse means that it is invertible; so "left invertibility implies right invertibility" is the same as "left (or right) invertibility implies invertibility".

Comment: Ah, this is very interesting. So, do any of the $C*$-algebras I mentioned have any of these properties?

Comment: Ah, so this includes all $II_1$ factors. Very interesting.

Comment: Whenever you have a faithful trace (not even necessarily bounded), this will hold: that is because $\tau(p - q) = \tau(p) - \tau(q) = \tau(v^*v) - \tau(vv^*) = 0$, and this implies that $p = q$ since $p - q$ is positive. 

As for discrete groups, the reduced C*-algebras have a faithful tracial state, and are therefore finite.