# Left/ Right Invertibility of an element in the spectrum

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. If $x \in A$ and $z \in \sigma(x^* x)$, why is $(x^*x - zI)$ neither left nor right invertible?

From [Left Invertibility Implies Right Invertibility in Certain $C^*$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567275/left-invertibility-implies-right-invertibility-in-certain-c-algebras), it seems like right invertibility implies left invertibility and vice versa. Unfortunately I don't have a copy of the book in hand, and I failed to prove it by contradiction.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $x^*x-zI$ is left invertible, then there is $a\in A$ with $a(x^*x-zI)=I$. But $z$ is a positive real number since $x^*x$ is positive, so taking adjoints yields $(x^*x- zI)a^*=I$ and thus $x^*x-zI$ is right invertible. Hence, it is invertible, contradiction.

Comment: Where do we need $z$ being positive? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Toasted_Brain The adjoint of $a(x^*x-zI)$ is $(x^*x-\overline{z}I)a^*$, and since $z$ is positive $z = \overline{z}$.

Comment: Thus what matters here is not really the fact that $z \geq 0$, but rather that it is a real number.